# How to break the loop when ReadString read EOF?

Tags: loops, go, server, eof

I am writing simple code for server and client, this is server part. I want to read the message from socket one line at a time and write it into newfile. But the code will stop running if it reads EOF. I want to know how to break the loop and keeps running the code below.
Thanks!

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "bufio"
import "net"
import "os"
import "log"
//import "strings" 


func check(e error) {
   if e != nil {
   panic(e) 
   }
}

func main() {
   fmt.Println("Launching server...")
   ln, _ := net.Listen("tcp", ":12003") 
   conn, _ := ln.Accept()
   defer ln.Close()
   defer conn.Close()

   //read file size(string)
   reader1 := bufio.NewReader(conn) 
   m_size, err1 := reader1.ReadString('\n')  
   check(err1)

   //print file size
   fmt.Printf("Upload file size: %s", m_size)

   //create new file
   out_file := "whatever.txt"
   newfile, err2 := os.Create(out_file) 
   check(err2)
   defer newfile.Close()


   //read and write line to new file
   writer1 := bufio.NewWriter(newfile)
   var i = 1
   line, err3 := reader1.ReadString('\n')
   check(err3)
   for err3 == nil {
       writer1.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%d %s", i, line)) 
       line, err3 = reader1.ReadString('\n')
       if err3 != nil { 
         break
       }
       i += 1
   }
   writer1.Flush()
   
   // get the new file's size and print
   stats, errr := os.Stat(out_file)
   if errr != nil {
      log.Fatal(errr)
   }
   fmt.Printf("Output file size: %d\n", stats.Size())

   // send message back to client
   writer2 := bufio.NewWriter(conn)
   m_size = strings.Replace(m_size, "\n", "", -1)
   newline := fmt.Sprintf("%s bytes received, %d bytes file generated",m_size,stats.Size()) 
   _, errw := writer2.WriteString(newline)
   check(errw)
   writer2.Flush()
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, if `line, err3 = reader1.ReadString('\n')` returns an EOF it should break out of the for loop and continue running code. What do you mean by "But the code will stop running if it reads EOF"? Does it panic somewhere else?

Comment: Trying to handle errors with `check(error)` is a poor pattern, especially since you're mixing it with inline error checks; it will be easier to maintain code that handles errors consistently. This is also an awkward implementation of what a `bufio.Scanner` already does, so using that may lead to clearer code where you can more easily find your mistake.

Comment: (1)The loop runs correctly until the end of the file, it stops working and doesn't enter the "if" part also print nothing. Afterward, I enforce the client to stop running, server here will show 'EOF' on terminal and finish the following codes. (2) I've tried bufio.Scanner already, but it scans nothing from socket.